# Easiest way to implement HTTP server that can send ROS messages

Tags: ros, python, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a web interface that sends http requests to a server. When this server receives a request it needs to send messages through a ROS topic. Since this server will be very simple I thought that the easiest way would be to use Flask to make a REST service, but ROS doesn't seem to play nice with Flask. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

## RESTful server that controls robot arm

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)
topic='mytopic'

def talker():
    rospy.loginfo('Starting talker')
    pub = rospy.Publisher(topic, String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rospy.loginfo('Talker started')
    
@app.route('/actions/execute', methods=['GET'])
def get_execute():
    action = request.args.get('action')
    if not action:
        abort(400)
    return action

if __name__ == '__main__':
    talker()
    rospy.loginfo("Starting Flask server")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If I comment out the line that calls talker() in main, the server starts correctly. If I execute it as shown however, I get the following:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1463411613.101553] Talker started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1463411613.102112] Starting Flask server
[INFO] [WallTime: 1463411613.576470] Talker started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1463411613.576941] Starting Flask server
```

And the Flask server never starts. I also can't kill the process with ctrl-c. Is there a way to make ROS work with Flask? And if there isn't, what is the easiest way to accomplish what I'm trying?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234418/easiest-way-to-implement-http-server-that-can-send-ros-messages/) by [biellls](https://answers.ros.org/users/26873/biellls/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iarc_team_erau](https://answers.ros.org/users/30058/iarc_team_erau/) on 2017-04-17**:
I am currently working on the same concept, however am also having to success. I am not super familiar with Flask, however it seems that both Flask and Ros require threads for their nodes. Have you had any success after this post?

**Comment by [biellls](https://answers.ros.org/users/26873/biellls/) on 2017-04-18**:
@iarc_team_erau as far as I know there is no way to use ROS in a python server. Look into rosbridge/roslibjs which let you do the same (it's what I ended up using https://github.com/biellls/arm_control_web/blob/710b47c04b48310651a73605ec13af12d712257a/static/resources/js/home.js#L33)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it can be made to work with rospy and Flask - the example below runs.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
    
import os
import rospy
import threading

from flask import Flask

from std_msgs.msg import UInt32

def ros_callback(msg):
    print(msg)

threading.Thread(target=lambda: rospy.init_node('example_node', disable_signals=True)).start()
rospy.Subscriber('/listener', UInt32, ros_callback)
pub = rospy.Publisher('/talker', UInt32, queue_size=10)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    msg = UInt32()
    msg.data = 1
    pub.publish(msg)
    
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=os.environ['ROS_IP'], port=3000)
```

---

Originally posted by [Sean Walters](https://answers.ros.org/users/38852/sean-walters/) with karma: 51 on 2018-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Void](https://answers.ros.org/users/28605/void/) on 2020-06-07**:
I can't get the subscriber to print the msg. Does the data not go to console?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realize that this thread is pretty old but I ran into the same use case and couldn't find any clear tutorials. I did find some working code; turns out the trick is to run ROS and Flask on different threads. That code has a lot of extra stuff going on so I distilled it down and put it into my own github repo. Here's the link, feel free to post any issues there: https://github.com/stoddabr/ros_flask

---

Originally posted by [stoddabr](https://answers.ros.org/users/56532/stoddabr/) with karma: 11 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1